# jquery get value from child <i> rel

Tags: jquery, children

Having this code:

```
<div class='adding_rows'>
    <i class='icons-added addRow add' rel='from_agreement_row,agreement_body_rows'></i>
    <label>Add Agreement Line</label>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to click on the `<div>` adding_rows and in jquery get the value from the `<i rel=''>` value

Tried :

```
$(".adding_rows").click(function() {
  var from_to_value = $(this).children().attr("rel");
})
```

which seems to work on the first instance of `<div class='adding_rows'>`
But stops there. Clicking on the next instance warns that "from_to_value is undefined"

Any one?

Comment: Seems to be working [here](https://jsbin.com/zepesoqigi/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: yep - cannot see how this is wrong

Comment: Maybe make sure you have your code wrapped in a `.ready()` function? If it works the first time I doubt this a problem. Perhaps you're calling that variable somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/4hq10p16/

You likely need to delegate if you add new divs to be clicked like this:

```
$("#container").on("click",".adding_rows",function() {
  var from_to_value = $(this).children().attr("rel");
})
```